# when I run the code below,I am getting an error as "index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0"

Tags: knn, python-3.8, recommendation-engine

This is my code below

```py
def recomend_book(book_name):
    b_id = np.where(books_rating_pivot.index == book_name)[0][0]
    _, recommendations = model.kneighbors(books_rating_pivot.iloc[b_id,:].values.reshape(1,-1))
    for i in range(len(recommendations)):
        if i == 0:
            print(f"For book \"{book_name}\" is recommended")
            if not i:
                print(books_rating_pivot.index[recommendations[i]])

recomend_book('Harry')
```

Comment: Show the full, minimal code needed to replicate your problem. For example: What is `np`? What is `books_rating_pivot`? What is `model`? etc.

Comment: If the `where` function on `np` returns an empty list, there are no items you can access. So `np.where(books_rating_pivot.index == book_name)[0][0]` will obviously fail.